# Why VB throws when looping through a collection

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting "Object variable or With block variable not set" for the following code.

```
Set entries = FindAllMatches(interestWorksheets, input_chapter_code)
For Each x In entries
   If x.Value = input_amount.Value Then // VBA STOPS HERE
   End if
Next
```

The debugger shows `entries` has 4 `Range` elements while `x` is `Nothing` (WHAT???)

`FindAllMatches` is defined as follows:

```
Function FindAllMatches(worksheets, input_chapter_code) As Collection
    Dim list As New Collection
    For Each ws In worksheets
        list.Add Item:=FindMatchInWorksheet(ws, input_chapter_code)
    Next
    Set FindAllMatches= list
End Function

Function FindMatchInWorksheet(worksheet, input_chapter_code) As Range
...
End Function
```

Comment: What data type is `x`? A collection element can by of any data type. What data type are you expecting that has a "value" property? Why are you using a collection at all? Wouldn't an array be much more appropriate?

Comment: this looks more like the job for a scripting dictionary, in my opinion.

Comment: Must say I just learned VBA 2 days ago. My logic is perfectly fine. A lot of optimization can be made to the code but that's not my concern here.  Coming from other languages I just find it difficult to understand what the VBA runner tries to tell me. Why is x `nothing` even though it contains elements (`Range`).

Comment: Are you sure `FindMatchInWorksheet` isn't returning Nothing?

Comment: @TimWilliams: you are right. After some digging, turns out `FindMatchInWorksheet` returns nothing (a string comparison fails but one of the cells have leading spaces). Why does the debugger show it contains 4 elements? That's so confusing.

Comment: `Nothing` is still "something" - a null reference.  It can be returned from a function and stored in a Collection.